# Is it possible to prefilter data when copying it from csv to sql table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a large .csv table that I want to insert into a Postgres DB. I don't need all rows from the table, is it possible to somehow filter it using SQL before it is uploaded to the database? Or the only option is to delete the rows I don't need afterward?

Comment: From Postgres 12 the [COPY command](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) has the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: You can use pandas in python, to manipulate the csv